# A question on diodes and resistors at the OR gate inputs of a 7432 IC

Tags: digital-logic

I'm trying to understand the reasons for the Schottky diodes(D1, D2, D3, D4) and 100 Ohm resistors used in the below schematics section:

[image]

The OR gates are from this: [2−Input OR Gate 74LS32](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/SN74LS32-D.PDF)

The diodes used are [BAT85S](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2189476.pdf)

As far as I know the inputs IN_C, IN_2, IN_1&A&B are pulses with either 0/6V or 0/12V types.

The whole circuit works in real, but I have the following questions:

1-) What could be the reasons for the diodes and the resistors in the inputs of the OR gates of the 74LS32?

2-) Can this 74LS32 handle 6V or 12V voltage inputs at its OR gates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could be the reasons for the diodes and the resistors in the inputs of the OR gates of the 74LS32?

They prevent damage to the chip if the input signals go negative. The diodes provide an alternate path for current to flow when that happens, and the resistors limit the current that can flow.

> Can this 74LS32 handle 6V or 12V voltage inputs at its OR gates?

No. Generally an input voltage higher than the positive supply voltage of a logic gate has the potential to damage the chip.

In newer chips this restriction would be given in an "Absolute Maximum Ratings" table. For these very very old chips, probably this table was once found in a general information about the whole LS family at the front of the databook, and On Semi just hasn't gotten around to including it in every individual datasheet in the years since things went online and those general information sections from the databook got hard to find.

Comment: Do you mean if the input signals IN_C, IN_2, IN_1&A&B goes negative "somehow" or the Gate inputs voltage goes to negative?  In that case will the current flow from GND to where? And what is D4 used for? Thanks in advance

Comment: Spec sheet states no max for inputs but that makes little sense.

Comment: If whatever's driving the inputs tries to drive them negative, current will flow from ground, through the diodes, through the resistors, and into that driving device. The voltage drop across the resistor will prevent the OR gates from seeing any voltage below about -0.2 V. D4 seems to just reduce the output voltage of the circuit by ~0.6 or 0.7 V.

Comment: Or D4 prevents back drive from whatever it is driving

Comment: @Trevor, It's an old old part. They used to put that information in the front of the databook if it applied to the whole part family. Motorola (now On Semi) did a lot of that. Do you think the part will survive if you apply -10 or +10 V?

Comment: YA I Know... odd they listed min but not max though @ThePhoton

Comment: It may,, you're basically back feeding into the emitter of a transistor. SO basically the cathode of a diode... @ThePhoton It must have a breakdown voltage somewhere though.

Comment: @ThePhoton Is that a common practice? Never seen before. Should digital logic gates be prevented this way in general?

Comment: @don, only if there's some reason to think a negative input voltage might be applied.

Comment: @doncarlos it depends what your inputs are. If they are coming from circuits that are more analog than digital it is prudent to protect against nagatives. Though the chip itself does provide some protection on it's own.

Comment: THe older TTL inputs wee pretty sturdy though.

Comment: Note: The "SN" prefix suggests this part is meant as a second source for the same-numbered TI part. And the [TI datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls32.pdf) is (just a tiny bit) more informative about the device's input protection circuit.

Comment: "ON Semiconductor LSTTL circuits do not use the
multi-emitter input structure that originally gave TTL its
name. Most LS elements use a DTL type input circuit with
Schottky diodes to perform the AND function, as
exemplified by D3 and D4 in Figure 1. Compared to the
classical multi-emitter structure, this circuit is faster and
increases the input breakdown voltage. Inputs of this type
are tested for leakage with an applied input voltage of 7.0 V
and the input breakdown voltage is typically 15 V or more."

Comment: Above from http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mcclurel/ON_Semiconductor_LSTTL_Data_DL121-D.pdf @ThePhoton

Comment: @Trevor, don't miss the part on the same page where it says "A
clamp current exceeding 2.0 mA and with a duration greater
than 500 ns can activate a parasitic lateral NPN transistor,
which in turn can steal current from internal nodes of an LS
circuit and thus cause logic errors."...Probably explains why this designer added the external clamps.

Comment: Makes sense  @ThePhoton

Answer (score 1):

> 1-) What could be the reasons for the diodes and the resistors in the
>   inputs of the OR gates of the 74LS32?

LSTTL input stages vary considerably. All have an internal Schottky clamp diode that conducts negative-going transients. Motorola warned that these are only meant to conduct 2 mA for a duration less than 500 ns. Otherwise, an internal parasitic NPN transistor can activate and cause logic errors. However, 74LS32 data sheet suggests that they *test* clamp current at -18 mA.
Perhaps your input signals contain negative transients (or steady-state levels) that exceed the above limits, requiring a more robust negative clamp. The resistors might be there to keep the internal clamp current small.

> 2-) Can this 74LS32 handle 6V or 12V voltage inputs at its OR gates?

Motorola tested LSTTL inputs for leakage current with +7V applied to an input. Typical breakdown voltage is 15V or more for diode-AND type inputs.
Another type of LSTTL input uses a PNP transistor. Motorola suggested that breakdown voltage exceeded +7V for these, as well as another "diode cluster" input type. Looks like +6V is OK. +12V might be close to (or over) the limit, especially if logic levels have transient edges.

This info was culled from "FAST AND LS TTL DATA" Motorola 1989, Fourth Edition. These dusty old books are gold, since they often don't get scanned and archived.